# Call stored procedure into recursion cte

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-cte

I have the following table

```
PNLTable([PnlId], 
          [Line], 
          [TotalisationId], 
          [Designation], 
          [Totalisation],
          ParentId).
```

I use the following query to get for each pnlid all children

```
;WITH CTE 
AS
(
    SELECT PNLId ,concat('/',cast(PNLId as nvarchar(MAX)) )as tree, PNLParentId
    FROM [dbo].[DimPNL]
    WHERE PNLParentId IS NULL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T1.PNLId,concat( CTE.tree ,'/',cast(t1.PNLId as nvarchar(MAX))), T1.PNLParentId
    FROM [dbo].[DimPNL] AS T1
    INNER JOIN CTE
    ON T1.PNLParentId = CTE.PNLId
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

I used a stored procedure spGetResult which updates Totalisation with some constraints .

How can I combine between `spGetResultstarting` and the query above in order to start updating recursively from the lowest children to the high level (roots)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just insert your ordered results into a `#temp` table and use a [cursor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) to iterate over the results something like this:

```
;WITH CTE 
AS
(
    SELECT PNLId ,concat('/',cast(PNLId as nvarchar(MAX)) )as tree, PNLParentId
    FROM [dbo].[DimPNL]
    WHERE PNLParentId IS NULL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T1.PNLId,concat( CTE.tree ,'/',cast(t1.PNLId as nvarchar(MAX))), T1.PNLParentId
    FROM [dbo].[DimPNL] AS T1
    INNER JOIN CTE
    ON T1.PNLParentId = CTE.PNLId
)
-- order the results into a #temp table
SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM CTE
ORDER BY PNLId, PNLParentId DESC -- set this accordingly

DECLARE @pnlId int   
DECLARE @pnlParentId int   

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT PNLId, PNLParentId 
FROM #temp 

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @pnlId, @pnlParentId    

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       -- call ytour stored proc with required params here
       Exec [spGetResultstarting] @pnlId, @pnlParentId

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @pnlId, @pnlParentId   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: Have you any idea how to insert the data that get from executing   Exec [spGetResultstarting] pnlId, pnlParentId everytime into table ?